# Centrally managed build profiles in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, sbt

I would like to be able to configure centrally something like "build profiles" which I can apply to multiple projects in Jenkins.

For instance, I want to setup a compile, email, deploy chain to be used by several projects. When I change something in this chain, I want to automatically apply the changes to all linked projects.

Is there a convenient way to do this? I am also open to suggestions for other build systems, as long as they can deal with sbt projects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see there is a [SBT plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/sbt+plugin) for Jenkins which looks popular-I haven't used it

I have used the jenkins job-dsl which covers [sbt out the box](https://github.com/jenkinsci/job-dsl-plugin/wiki/Job-reference#sbt). This works by a build step in a job to create/regenerate other jobs (with an optional template)

The problem with having a generic job building separate projects is that all the job history gets merged together. I think it is better to use stand-alone jobs for each task and the job-dsl will allow you to do that

Answer (score 0):

[TeamCity](http://www.jetbrains.com/teamcity/) supports [build configuration templates](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD8/Build+Configuration+Template) out of the box and recently added basic [sbt support](http://blog.jetbrains.com/teamcity/2014/02/sbt-runner-for-teamcity/).